# How to find the total upload/download size

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, logic, web-traffic

I am in a project which is a imternet monitoring software. This needs the capability to show the total upload/download size. That means the calculation of traffic through the internet. Can any body say logic|API which can do this.

Comment: In general, you either have to ask the provider for the data size before shipping or calculate the amount of data received.  Some protocols may actually provide the data size in the message / packet.

Comment: @Thomas I can't ask the provider. Because this app needs to tape the download size even at browsing. And thanks for the idea of knowing pocket size from the protocal. I am digging on that part.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggesting creating a [Layered Service Provider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider)